# Building Flasgger/Swagger API in python3 exception

Tags: python-3.x, api, flask-restful, flasgger

I am building a Flasgger/Swagger API in python. When I input the values into the parameters and execute the code I am seeing the following error. I have also share exception images.

```
"""Example endpoint returning a list of colors by value
    This is using docstrings for specifications.
    ---
    tags:
      - Iris Prediction API Input values
    parameters:
      - name: s_length
        in: path
        type: string
        required: true
        default:
      - name: s_width
        in: path
        type: string
        required: true
        default:
      - name: p_length
        in: path
        type: string
        required: true
        default:
      - name: p_width
        in: path
        type: string
        required: true
        default:
    definitions:
      value:
        type: object
        properties:
          value_name:
            type: string
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/Color'
      Color:
        type: string
    responses:
      200:
        value: prediction details
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/value'
        examples:
          rgb: ['red', 'green', 'blue']
"""
```

**ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')**

[Flasgger Localhost image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9rpz.png)
[Exception Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s47K4.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out by changing these parameters.

```
        in: query
        type: integer
```